# How to reference another answer

Tags: discussion, questions

The `@` makes it possible to reference another person commenting the same answer. But how can I reference another person answering the same question?

Update: This question refers to comments of an answer.

Comment: Just link to it? There's a share button below each answer where you can pick up a link.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer

Comment: Can you say more about why you need to reference another question and is this a common thing for you to need to do? Kinda curious.

Answer (score 20):

You can't. Not in a way that will notify the owner of that other answer, anyway.

The best you can do is something like "[According to ceving's question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277839/871050)".

Comment: It's be nice if you'd explain how you got that into your answer.

Comment: Literally just link to the target post and write something descriptive.

Comment: I never was aware of the "share" link besides edit/flag. I only found that in another post then. Cheers, Naruto

Comment: And to go to a specific answer use #answerId at the end of the link. [like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277839/how-to-reference-another-answer#answer-277840)

Comment: The 'Share' at the bottom of an answer lets you copy a link to it.

Answer (score -1):

Based on [J. Steen's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277839/how-to-reference-another-answer/424276#comment121691_277839), here is what I do.

**Please note**: this answer is intended **ONLY** to illustrate how to include a URL to a SO answer, but is **NOT** intended to recommend how to properly cite a reference in a paper or the like.

## Solution Steps

1. Click the *Share* link directly underneath the answer you want to link to.

   [image]
2. Click the link titled *Copy link*.

   [image]
3. Embed the copied URL into either an SO question, answer, comment, or other SO content using markdown syntax.  For example:

   ### Markdown Example Syntax

   ```
   Here is an example of an [amazing answer on SO][linked_answer]!

   [linked_answer]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67980305/1615978
   ```

## Conclusion

If you perform all three steps correctly, SO should render your Markdown text thusly.

### Markdown Example Rendered

Here is an example of an [amazing answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67980305/1615978)!

Comment: You forgot a critical step.  You must quote and cite the relevant information.  Submitting an answer, with only a link to another answer, isn't acceptable and will quickly be deleted.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I guess I don't know how to properly cite other answers.  Writing has never been my strong point.  Just trying to share a bit of knowledge.  But, if you can give me a pointer I'd appreciate it!

Comment: I did give you advice. You don’t know to cite and quote external sources?

Comment: I do know how to cite and quote sources.  And I did, but it seems I didn't cite my source up to the SO standards. So, I thought I'd ask for your advice on how I SO expects me to cite sources.  Is there a reference manual somewhere?

Comment: You failed to mention that, in your answer, which explains how to reference another answer.

Comment: @SecurityHound The context I intended was only technical on how to include a URL to a SO answer.  I didn't intend it to be interpretted as a guide on how to reference properly using the rules of English writing and what not.  Seems like that might have been the misunderstanding.